# SQL iPython Magic Extension won't load

Tags: python, sql, ipython

Just installed the iPython-SQL extenson, but when I run

```
%load_ext sql
```

I get an error "The sql module is not an IPython extension." 
I installed it via pip by

```
pip install ipython-sql
```

and when that didn't seem to work, even by downloading the file from Github and executing the code.
Searching "The sql module is not an IPython extension." itself yielded 0 results in Google, so I am a little lost on what I might be doing wrong.

I am running OSX El Capitan (with SIS disabled), and my Python/iPython version is as below:

```
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 19 2015, 18:31:17) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you're using Anaconda's Python, make sure you install with the associated package manager conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipython-sql=0.3.6
```

Source: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ipython-sql

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the error on a notebook that no module named `no module named sql`.
I did `pip install python-sql` and it then it gave the same error you had. I used `%reload_ext sql` instead of `%load_ext sql` and it seems to be working. Maybe it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had a file called `sql.py` in my working folder...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Jupyter Lab` use the command

```
 %pip install ipython-sql
```

to install ipython-sql and then try

```
 %load_ext sql
```

again

That works like a charm for me.