# I was trying loading python extension for SQL but when i tried i got this

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook

[Find Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7ilA.png)

i was trying to connect my db-2 using python and hence running sql queries. But at the very fist line i have been stuck here, I had searched for it but i have not got any clues yet. some of them were not working. first it was showing me sql module not found and not this problem i am facing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967288/sql-ipython-magic-extension-wont-load might be related to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed sql library? If not, install it using pip or conda:

1. installing using pip: ***pip install python-sql***
2. import library to your code: ***import sql***